# Socket.io Rooms

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, socket.io

In below program, cashier.js call join_session/room in server, every time it emits cart_items, then the server will emit it to all client in that specific room. So the question is this the right way to do it, do i really need to call join_session/room in my cashier.js every time it emits data?

server.js

```
let nsp = io.of('namespace_name');
let session;

nsp.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('join_session', function (client_ip) {
        session = client_ip;
        socket.join(session);
        console.log('New session (' + session + ')');

        socket.on('cart_items', function (data) {
            console.log(session);
            console.log(data);
            nsp.to(session).emit("cart_items", data);
        }); 
    });
});
```

cashier.js

```
socket.on('connect', function () {
    socket.emit('join_session', session);
    socket.emit('cart_items', { name: item.name, price: item.price });
});
```

customer.js

```
socket.on('connect', function () {
        socket.emit('join_session', session);

        socket.on('cart_items', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
```

FYI when i try to do this in my cashier.js

```
socket.on('connect', function () {
        socket.emit('join_session', session);
    });

//on button click
    socket.emit('cart_items', { name: item.name, price: item.price });
```

There were times that client 1 sends data to client 2 and vice versa.